# Recovering a Matrix After Multiplication By Its Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Given an arbitrary symmetric N-by-N matrix A, how can its original values be calculated from $P$?

$$ P = A'A$$

Both $A$ and $P$ have \( \frac{N^2-N}{2}+N \) degrees of freedom.

Edit: added the constraint that A is symmetric

Comment: Look up Cholesky decomposition

Comment: You cannot estimate $A.$ Suppose $A$ is the Cholesky decomposition of $P,$ which is easy to compute and numerically stable. Then, given any orthogonal matrix $R,$ meaning $R^T \; R = I,$ then consider $B = R A.$ We get $$B^T \; B = (RA)^T \; R A = A^T \; R^T \; R \; A = A^T \; I \; A = P. $$

Comment: I apologize - the original question was formulated poorly.  The matrix A is symmetric as well.

Comment: There can be many different looking symmetric matrices, each of whose square is the identity matrix.

Comment: The converse of Will's observation also holds: ie.  if $A$ is
nonsingular,  and $P=A_1^TA_1=A_2^TA_2$, then $R=A_2A_1^{-1}=R^T$ is
orthogonal and $A_2=RA_1$. In this case if you think of the
Euclidean lattice generated by the columns of $A$, then $P=A^TA$ is
the Gram matrix (the quadratic form) and this just say that the Gram
matrix determines the lattice upto a rotation. But this does not
answer the question, after finding $P=A^TA$ by Cholesky, we know all
solutions are given by $RA, R \in O(N)$, some  of the $R$ will make
$RA$ symmetric.

Comment: There seem to be two unknown (google)s in this discussion. Could at least one of you **please** take a moment to choose a pseudonym, or better still your actual name?

Comment: To the OP: do you want all solutions, or just a possible solution? Are you perhaps also assuming P is **positive**?

Comment: @Yemon, if I leave my mouse arrow resting on either unknown google, at the bottom of my browser it shows the user number, 1894 for one and 21740 for the OP. I am 3324 and you are 763, so 1894 started long after you but long before i did. Also, Gordon Pall used quaternions to parametrize $SO_3 \mathbb Q,$ from what I can see his recipe can always be rearranged by permutations to be a symmetric orthogonal matrix.  I think his recipe is essentially the same thing they use for computer graphics now.

Comment: I really do not know where this habit of using $A^T$ or $A'$ where $A$ is symmetric comes from...

Answer (score 3):

Well, that depends on the ground field.

- If the field is $\mathbb R$, there exists a unique positive semidefinite square root $\sqrt P$. If $P$ is positive definite, then $A$ is any matrix of the form $AD$ where $D$ is co-diagonal to $A$ and is a sign-matrix, *i.e* $D^2=I_n$. If $P$ is singular, there might be other solutions, but at least the ones above are valid.
- If the field is $\mathbb C$, the situation is much worse. For instance, if $P=0_2$, there are non-zero solutions $A$, say
  $$z\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \pm i \\\\ \pm i & -1 \end{pmatrix},\qquad z\in\mathbb C.$$